# Spring Transaction Management in the Service Layer

Tags: spring, transactions

I'm using tomcat and Spring 3.1 to develop a Maven webapp. The data source is defined as JNDI in tomcat. I'm thinking about using @Transactional annotation.

How to implement transaction in the service layer?  Could you please point me at the right direction as what kind of transaction management should I use? JTA, JPA or others? And how to configure it? Which dependencies do I need?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't use JPA unless that's your implementation.

It's far more likely that you're using JTA.

[Here](http://www.baeldung.com/2011/12/26/transaction-configuration-with-jpa-and-spring-3-1/) is a Spring transactional tutorial.

Comment: Thanks for you help. We are actually using JPA/Hibernate. But that's in DAO layer. The tutorial you gave uses JPA TX manager. Is there another one using JTA with detailed configuration and dependency instruction? And more importantly do I need to configure the data source? As our data source is defined as JNDI resource in tomcat context. How do I configure it in this case? Thanks again.

Comment: I thought it showed both.  I'd recommend consulting the Spring docs; they spell it out.  Of course the persistence technology is in the DAO layer; transactions belong on the service.  You do have to configure the data source; I'd recommend a JNDI data source.  But all of that has to be done whether you use transactions or not.  You're over analyzing or not understanding this.